# Following error when trying to use std::sort: In template: called object type 'bool' is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c++

I want to reverse sort a custom container with custom objects, so when sorting this way:
(this is part of the .cpp)

```
bool PictureContainer::isGreater(const Picture& i, const Picture& j) {
    return (i.getId() > j.getId());
}


void PictureContainer::sortRev() {
    sort(picture, picture + tam, isGreater()); 
//< If I try with isGreater, without parenthesis, it says I need to make it static and then it gives same error again.
}
```

this is part of the .h

```
class PictureContainer {
private:
    int size;
    Picture *picture;
public:
    PictureContainer();

    PictureContainer(int maxSize);

    bool isGreater (const Picture& i, const Picture& j);

    void sortRev();
```

Comment: If you really need `isGreater` to be part of the `PictureContainer` class, mark `isGreater` as `static` and pass `PictureContainer::isGreater` as the third parameter to `std::sort()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to use a non-static member function directly as the comparator for `std::sort()`. There are a few options:

1. Mark `PictureContainer::isGreater` as static, and pass `PictureContainer::isGreater` to `std::sort()`.
2. Since the implementation of `isGreater` does not access anything that's only available from the `PictureContainer` class, we may also make it a free function and pass `isGreater` to `std::sort()`.
3. In case the implementation of `isGreater` has to access some members (or member functions) that's only available within an instance of `PictureContainer`, we may use a lambda inside the implementation of `PictureContainer::isRev` as the argument. This is the most flexible solution. For example:

```cpp
void PictureContainer::sortRev() {
    sort(picture, picture + tam, [this](const Picture& lhs, const Picture& rhs) {
        return this.isGreater(lhs, rhs);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`isGreater()` is a member function of `PictureContainer`.  You cannot pass it to `std::sort` like that.  The easiest way to fix this is to make `isGreater()` a stand-alone non-member function.

Generally, you can pass pointers to member functions around, but the syntax is convoluted, and you need the object of the class. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/function-pointer-to-member-function-in-cplusplus